# Is there a way to Preload data to a report in PowerBI Report Server?

Tags: hive, powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I'm fairly new to PowerBI so I'll try to explain as best as I can:

I am using PowerBI Desktop to design a dashboard. I'm using an ODBC connection to HIVE. The final file weighs a little under 1GB. I don't have any problem loading the .pbix file to the Report Server. However when I open the report it takes about 5 minutes to load the tables and the report itself.

Since I am using an Import I assume this time is taken to load the data into the cache right? Is there a way to make this process faster? Is there a way to preload data into the cache so that it opens faster?

Bonus: How can I avoid size issues if my file gets bigger than 1GB? I am loading the file directly from my local Power BI Desktop to Report Server.

Comment: You should check if the problem is in your visualizations. Use performance analizer inside powerbi desktop or DaxStudio; You can also add blank tab and upload report, then check open time; DaxStudio Give you also option to verify the size of each table; Do you use a star schema or so?

Comment: Thanks I will try to use performance analyser and let you know. What would be the purpose of creating the blank tab? Yes I use star schema. I have many fact tables (6) and many dim tables (20).